# With loopback built-in methods, catch an error and return no error

Tags: loopbackjs

I use Loopback 3.
With my client-side application, I use the method POST User to create a new user. If the email adress already exists in basis, the server responds with an error of status 422.
I would like to catch this error, so that the serveur returns *no error*.

I tried to use afterRemoteError like this :

```
User.afterRemoteError('create', function(context, next) {
  if (context.error && context.error.statusCode === 422
      && context.error.message.indexOf('Email already exists') !== -1
      && context.req.body && context.error.message.indexOf(context.req.body.email) !== -1) {
    context.error = null;
    next(null);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

but this doesn't work, the server still returns the original error. If I try to replace the `next(null)` with a `next(new Error('foo'))` then the serveur returns the new error, but I didn't find how to return no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanks to my colleague that find the solution to the problem!

The fact is that afterRemoteError is triggered to late in the flow of the middlewares if we use `next()`. The solution is to self send the response with an express syntax:

```
User.afterRemoteError('create', function(context, next) {
    if (context.error && context.error.statusCode === 422
        && context.error.message.indexOf('Email already exists') !== -1
        && context.req.body && context.error.message.indexOf(context.req.body.email) !== -1)
    {
        context.res.status(200).json({foo: 'bar'});
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```